# How to convert Corel Draw design into HTML design?

Tags: html, website-design

I have a Corel Draw .cdr file which has a full design of a web page. Is there any way to convert that design into HTML template?

Answer (score 1):

You need to code the html and css by hand to get a good result. Even if CorelDraw allows you to save your template to html it will never result in good and usable code.